# Update dictionary value in Django Updateview

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I have a char field that is inside a model in Django. The data I save in that field is in dictionary format, just like this `{'name': 'Jon', 'age': 25}`. How can I update that using Django updateview?

Comment: You can make use of a `JsonField`, which is probably better since it does the wrapping automatically between Json and the Python objects.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know there's such a JSON field. I'm new to Django and your comment is a big help.